# How to withdraw 401K?

Tags: united-states, 401k, withdrawal

I worked in company A with 401k account. I was laid off and moved to company B which also had 401K account.

When I was in B, I tried to split my 401k in A into cash and move remaining to B. So the 401k in A issued me two checks one for bank deposit and another for move remaining to B.

Before I deposited or used the checks, I quit company B as well. Now it has been 1 year the checks were issued. Now the question is how should I take my 401k from A and move to B. My ultimate goal is to cash out money from A.

I was under work visa called H1B and now I am back in home country.

Answer (score 7):

You withdrew the 'cash' portion, and will pay tax on it.

How was the check "another for move remaining to B" issued? Was it payable to you? If so, it's too late, it's your money and the whole account was cashed out.

If it was payable to B, you should have had it sent directly to their custodian, are you saying you still have that check? You might need to ask A to reissue the check to you, since you are no longer in the US. I'm not sure if you can roll it to an IRA at this point.